# Facing trouble running an old xcode project in old macOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to install an old Xcode project built-in Xcode 8.8.2. But unfortunately, whenever I am trying to install project it's showing some errors.

So, the project is an old Origami studio (built by Facebook). Currently, we are trying to install into an old macOS El Capitan, under Xcode 8.8.2.

Also, I am new to Xcode development. So, I may need step by step assistance to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Origami Studio projects can only be opened through Origami Studio. Origami Studio doesn't export code that can be used in native build processes and the files cannot be opened properly in a code editor.